# Cocoa's TextField returns action control

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a TextField (`IBOutlet NSTextField *commandInput;`) to get an input as a command, and I have a Button to run the command by calling this method:

```
- (IBAction) runShell: (id)sender;
{
    // get the string from inputItem
    NSString* item = [commandInput stringValue];

    system([item UTF8String]);
    NSLog(@"%s", [item UTF8String]);
}
```

[image]

Can I remove the Button? I mean, can I run the runShell method when I hit enter **in** the TextField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says so explicitly:

> An `NSTextField` object is a kind of `NSControl` that displays text that the user can select or edit and that sends its action message to its target when the user presses the Return key while editing.

Comment: Ah, yes. I tried to Control-Drag/Drop both directions from/to Object and UI object. And it works fine. Thanks.